# Matching special characters with Regex lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex

I am receiving messages which have underscores:

```
  _omgitworks_
```

However, when these messages are formatted by our HTML wire formatter we receive
them with backslashes infront of the underscores:

```
  \_omgitworks\_
```

I created the following regex to capture the backslashes and remove them so the
text tokenizes correctly:

```
rawInput.replace(/\\([_])/g, '$1');
```

However, there is an edge case of when a user italicizes text. When the user
utalicizes text, we receive the messages with NO backslashes but with
underscores - and we want to remove the underscores. This is what the received
text looks like:

```
_omgitworks_
```

I am trying to design a regex which **matches a backslash followed by an
underscore and then replaces the backslash (but not the underscore) OR if there
is only a underscore with no bachslash, it only matches the underscore.**

I tried to implement this using lookaheads:

```
var regex = /\\(?=_)|_/g;
var string = '\\_omgitworks\\_'
string.replace(regex, '')
>>> "omgitworks"
```

But it is removing the backslash AND the underscore instead of just the
underscore. Are there any nuances to lookaheads that I am overlooking?

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to remove, a simple example of this or that before and after will do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex:

```
\\(_)|(^|[^\\])_
```

And replace with `$1$2`.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jU5aK8/1)

*Explanation*:

- `\\(_)` - the first alternative matching `\` followed with a `_` (Capture group 1)
- `|` - or...
- `(^|[^\\])_` - another alternative matching start of string or any character other than `\` (captured into Group 2) followed with an underscore.

In the relacement part, we restore the captures using the backreferences. In JS, failed groups are always pre-populated with an empty string, so it is safe to use even if the capture groups happen to be empty.

```js
var re = /\\(_)|(^|[^\\])_/g; 
var str = '_omgitworks_\n\\_omgitworks\\_';
var result = str.replace(re, '$1$2');
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>"+ result + "</pre>";
```

Comment: I missunderstood the **remove underscore** part of the question. +1 for your answer that does it correctly :)

Comment: There is a slight problem with this - perhaps this is my fault for not describing all the edge cases. This regex strips out underscores that occur within words. For example: brown_dog becomes 'browndog'

Comment: Could you provide some examples? I mean, is that `brown_dog` a standalone string or part of longer text? Try `\\(_)|(^|[^\\])\b_\B|(^|[^\\])\B_\b` and replace with `$1$2$3`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rI9fI8/1).

Comment: So, did you try the suggestion?